# Загрузить HTML код в переменную

Tags: javascript, html, парсер, download

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью `JavaScript` можно получить `HTML` код любого веб-сайта по ссылке? И потом передать его в переменную или в `*.txt` файл?

Answer (score 2):

Получения любых данных с другого сервера не по средствам стандартного `API` называется "парсинг", спарсить с помощью обычного браузерного `JS` мы можем любую веб-страницу или вообще любой веб-адрес, то есть мы можем абсолютно полностью настроить `HTTP` запрос с браузера по средствам `JS`, и делается это с помощью технологии `XMLHttpRequest`, она позволяет нам сделать абсолютно любой `HTTP` запрос по средствам браузерного `JS`(не стоит обращать внимание на `XML` в начале названия технологии, он не играет там ключевую роль). Над этой технологией есть миллион оберток, вроде `Ajax` в `jQuery`, которые упрощают и так очень простую работу с этой технологией.

Если вам нужно что-то сохранить в файл, то советую смотреть в сторону `File API` у браузеров, или в сторону `NodeJS`.

Пример:

```
var perem;
$.ajax({
    url: "site.com",
}).done(function(data) {
    preme = data;
});
```

А потом из этой переменной можем сохранять в файл.

Comment: Можно пример кода? Спасибо

Comment: Обновил ответ, если вас удовлитворяет, пометьте его как верный.